# How to extend switch case dynamic property getter in base class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a base class that fetches attributes like below, to map between JSON/C# names:

```
[JsonPropertyName("foo")]
[DataMember(Name = "foo")]
public FooAttribute { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("bar")]
[DataMember(Name = "bar")]
public BarAttribute { get; set; }

public object? this[string attributeName]
        {
            get
            {
                switch (attributeName)
                {
                    case "foo":
                        return FooAttribute;
                    case "bar":
                        return BarAttribute;
                    case ....
    
                    default:
                        try
                        {
                            return Attributes[attributeName];
                        }
                        catch (KeyNotFoundException)
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

But now I want to make derived classes that implement all of the above, with additional attributes such as ChildA: `spam : SpamAttribute` and ChildB: `eggs : EggsAttribute`.

How can I accomplish that, without copy-pasting the entire switch case?

Comment: this is a horrible idea. First off don´t use a `KeyNotFoundException` for usual program-flow. Second if you know the attributes of your type at compile-time, why not provide them, e.g. `myInstance.FooAttribute`, instead of `myInstance["FooAttribute"]`? You don´t need the latter for serialization to or deserialization from JSON, as you already provided the mapping via the attributes `JsonPropertyName`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to contradict your concept of base class with string indexer and storing additional values in Attributes dictionary. It isn't the best of, but I have already met this solution in the past too.

```
class Base
{
    private IDictionary<string, object> Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.Ordinal);

    public virtual object this[string attributeName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (attributeName)
            {
                default:
                    Attributes.TryGetValue(attributeName, out var valueOrNull);
                    return valueOrNull;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Descendant1 : Base
{
    // ... FooAttribute and BarAttribute props here ...

    public override object this[string attributeName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (attributeName)
            {
                case "foo":
                    return FooAttribute;
                case "bar":
                    return BarAttribute;
                default:
                    return base[attributeName];
            }
        }
    }
}

class Descendant2 : Descendant1
{
    // ... BaconAttribute and EggsAttribute props here ...

    public override object this[string attributeName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (attributeName)
            {
                case "bacon":
                    return BaconAttribute;
                case "eggs":
                    return EggsAttribute;
                default:
                    return base[attributeName];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I omitted props for sake of simplicity. In case which I met the property getters read their values from dictionary too.

Comment: What I don't understand here is, what if the base class implements `"base_attribute"/BaseAttribute`? Right now the base implementation is just blank? Is it because `Base.base_attribute` automatically leads to `Base.BaseAttribute`?

Comment: yes, you can decorate swith in base class with more cases, e.g. for some base props. Or you can remove switch from base class.

Comment: You should also consider that indexer and props should be consistent and return the appropriate values.